# Type annotations with Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, annotations

I am trying to understand the type annotations of Python 3.10.
Please consider the functions:

```
def A(n: int):
    return [k for k in range(n+1)]   
    
def B(n: int):
    return B(n - 1) + [n] if n > 0 else [0]
```

The type hints as shown in VSCode are:

```
(function) A: (n: int) -> list[int]   
(function) B: (n: int) -> (Any | list[int])
```

Why is the return type not list[int] in both cases?

More specifically: how do I have to write the recursive variant B
to get only the type list[int] as return type?

Comment: In the second case it just can’t figure out the type of the `B(n - 1) + [n]` expression automatically and uses `Any`. You can add the correct type hint yourself.

Comment: Why not _specify_ the type, so it can be _checked_?